# Linux - Check if a file has multiple lines

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a command or bash function to check if a file has multiple lines?
Lets say i have these two files:

**foo.txt**

```
Hello World
```

**bar.txt**

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: try `wc -l` command.

Comment: You can use `wc -l` to count the number of lines in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with this command:

```
wc -l foo.txt | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

**Output**: 1

```
wc -l bar.txt | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

**Output**: 2

This shows the number of lines, in a script I can check wheter this number is bigger than 1 or not and my problem is solved.

Comment: Use `wc -l < bar.txt` - there's no need for awk here at all.

Comment: Broken. Counts newlines rather than lines. echo -n -e 'ab\ncd' | wc -l reports just 1, though there are two lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script:

name:test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

back=`wc -l $1`
nl=${back:0:1}

if [ $nl = "1" ];then
    echo "single line"
else
    echo "multi lines"
fi
```

use this command to change the file mod:

```
chmod a+x test.sh
```

Then execute the script,paramater is the file you want to test:

```
./test.sh hello
```

Comment: What happens if the name of the file contains spaces, or characters such as `*`? What happens if the file has 10-19, or 100-199 lines?

Comment: This needs you to add regular expression in the bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
cat foo.txt | wc -l
```

This would read the file and return a count of the lines within the file.

`cat` - read the file
piped into `wc` (word count) `-l` (No. of lines)

Comment: this is a [useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: Why not just `wc -l foo.txt` or `wc -l < foo.txt` ?